# How to stream a video from facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to build an Android app with selected videos from the facebook. The app talks to my server, which provides the video ids to the app in the JSON format. like this

```
[
  {
    id: "869532303215810"
  },
  {
    id: "2792785464077828"
  }
]
```

Though this method of just passing the video id just works for the Youtube Player Api: [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

I could not find enough resources on the internet which will do the same for the facebook video. I want to play a fb video using their api.

I have tried their [Graph API](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/869532303215810?access_token=xxx).

This is what I am getting as a response:

```
{
  "description": "MS CAMELTOE LMAO",
  "updated_time": "2017-05-31T20:03:11+0000",
  "id": "869532303215810"
}
```

But I can't find streaming information here.

There seems to be Embed for the web:
[Embedded Video & Live Video Player](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player#).

But I can't find the same for the Android! Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to request the *source* field

```
$ oksocial https://graph.facebook.com/1973801359519107?fields=source | jq .
{
  "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-29/18846178_1977083652514776_2979079068437184512_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjE1MDAsInJsYSI6MjU3OSwidmVuY29kZV90YWciOiJzZCJ9&rl=1500&vabr=348&oh=d0e43bafa8d9740c205c494f0fde0b5d&oe=5932C4FA",
  "updated_time": "2017-06-01T21:43:02+0000",
  "id": "1973801359519107"
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a way I can find out about the usage limits for this API? Should I need to pay fb, if I make too many requests per day?

Comment: I don't know, try your app dashboard linked from https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003209/how-to-get-large-image-from-facebook-graph-api-for-video @Yuri, Can you please take a look at this?