# How to get large image from facebook graph api for video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video-streaming

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/1505552949567253?fields=source,length,picture.type(large),permalink_url&access_token=bla
```

But I am getting a very small image, which needs to be enlarged a lot thereby losing a lot of quality, is there a way that i can specify the picture quality as well in the request

Response is like this

```
{
"source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t43.1792-4/22493904_1523143121101563_3196186272225820672_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9oZCJ9&oh=eea85d53fc6e77187d69d6460ad1af3e&oe=5A97C361",
"length": 197.737,
"picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/s160x160/22642569_1505562656232949_2963030712682283008_n.jpg?oh=c2f2fa4ff4f007971c361bfde644ae24&oe=5B19AF67",
"permalink_url": "/InspiredLifePage/videos/1505552949567253/",
"id": "1505552949567253"
}
```

The returned image is this small

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `thumbnails` field and look for the object with `is_preferred` set to `true`. `picture` doesn't respond to modifiers.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. However I am getting this
```
{
"error": {
"message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 102,
"fbtrace_id": "FZWqejIKrwT"
}
}
```
I need to use app access token, not the user access token

Comment: Seems to be working as designed. You shouldn't be using the app access token for these calls. The app token is for admin calls.

Comment: Hey, I can use app access token to get the videos AFAIK. And I am already getting the video source, permalink, even the picture .. It's just that I need a bigger picture. Why do you think I should not use app access token? Can you point me to some related info on this?

Comment: App tokens can only retrieve limited data. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens This is the way the API is designed. 

`Some user data that would normally be visible to an app that's making a request with a user access token isn't always visible with an app access token. If you're reading user data and using it in your app, you should use a user access token instead of an app access token.`

Comment: I get that, but I don't see how giving the app token bigger picture is different that giving them a smaller picture? Do I get to make a request to your support team?

Comment: It was never meant for that data. It's really that simple. Facebook provides limited data access for the app token for the purposes of admin tasks not consuming data. You can try to file a bug if you think that's incorrect https://developers.facebook.com/bugs however, I doubt that will work.